# How to change the Windows-1251 encoding in a csv file with the actual UTF-8

Tags: python, pandas, csv, notepad++

I'm trying to translate "hieroglyphs" into Russian letters. I took a [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasnaek/youtube-new) (RUvideos.csv file), uploaded it via pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('RUvideos.csv',encoding = "utf-8")
```

I took the "title" column (pd.Series) and saved it to another CSV file:

```
x=data.title.copy()
x.to_csv(join(fld,'title.csv'))
```

then I opened the resulting file using Notepad++, because there are tips that you can use it to change the encoding in CSV:

[image: Problem with encoding]

There is UTF-8 encoding, although the characters are actually encoded in Win-1251. I tried all the encodings, it didn't help.

Who knows how to change Win-1251 to UTF-8 in this case?

I changed the encoding in Excel, but the file splitting into columns is broken when executing the read_csv function.

Comment: Maybe you should try `x.to_csv(join(fld,'title.csv'), encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: I tried it. It didn't help

Comment: Can you add a link to the actual file? (or least a handful of rows of it)

Comment: The link is at the top of the question

Comment: The problem was partially solved with the help of the Shtirlitz plugin built into Notepad++. However, some of the characters are not decrypted, and some of the decrypted characters were determined incorrectly.